# handling UI events in asp.net mvp

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, mvp

been breaking my head over mvp pattern over the last two days. can someone please guide me to a book or some source with an illustration. basically trying to wire up some ui events i.e. drop down list changed, grid view edit,delete etc and passing the event args what properties need to be exposed etc..

your help would be appreciated..

Jack

Answer (score 1):

Hey here's an article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ModelViewPresenter.aspx) with a trivial example.. hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

try this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx